# It is possible to launch uwp app without installing

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

Is there anyway to launch Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app without installing it?
I want to launch uwp app from the unpacked appx folder but IDK how.
As far as I know there's just one way to open uwp app it's install it then open it...

Comment: You need to "deploy" it and before you need to package it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/ *"To distribute or sell your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, you need to create an app package for it."* in development mode there are some tweaks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/loose-file-registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to launch uwp app from the unpacked appx folder but IDK how.

It is not possible to do that. Unlike some desktop apps that could be directly launched from a .exe file, UWP apps needs to be deployed or installed first like @Simon Mourier mentioned. UWP can't directly launched by the appx file.